# removeView() AlertDialog en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, alertdialog

Estoy tratando de mostrar una lista personalizada dentro de un alertDialog, todo va bien hasta cuando el usuario clickea en un item seguido de ello el alertDialog se cierra y cuando deseo volver a mostrar el alertDialog me sale este error:

```
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
AlertDialog dialog; //variable global
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.conductor);
    cargar_mensajes();
}

private void cargar_mensajes() {
    String url = url;
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try{
                lista_mensajes = new ListView(Conductor.this);
                JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                JSONObject data = res.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONArray mensajes = data.getJSONArray("mensajes");
                for(int i = 0; i<mensajes.length();i++){
                    JSONObject item = mensajes.getJSONObject(i);
                    int id_mensaje = item.getInt("id_mensaje");
                    String mensaje_cond = item.getString("mensaje");
                    //LISTA PERSONALIZADA
                    datos_mensajes = new Datos_mensajes(id_mensaje, mensaje_cond);
                    arrayList.add(datos_mensajes);
                    Adaptador_mensajes adaptador_mensajes = new Adaptador_mensajes(Conductor.this,arrayList);
                    lista_mensajes.setAdapter(adaptador_mensajes);

                    lista_mensajes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            TextView txt_id_mensaje_conductor = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_id_mensaje_conductor);
                            TextView txt_mensaje_conductor = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_mensaje_conductor);
                            String id_mensaje_conductor_txt = txt_id_mensaje_conductor.getText().toString();
                            String mensaje_conductor_txt = txt_mensaje_conductor.getText().toString();

                            Toast.makeText(Conductor.this, mensaje_conductor_txt+" "+id_mensaje_conductor_txt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.dismiss(); //CIERRO ALERTDIALOG
                        }
                    });
                    //FIN LISTA PERSONALIZADA
                }
            }catch (JSONException e){

            }
            onConnectionFinished();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Conductor.this,"Error al cargar los mensajes",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            onConnectionFailed();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            params.put("Authorization", "Basic "+auth);
            return params;
        }
    };
    addToQueue(request);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_conductor,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.sms_conductor:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Conductor.this);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setView(lista_mensajes);
            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog = builder.show();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Todo esto lo hago con un menu que muestro en la parte superior derecha.
todo esta correcto el unico error es el que mencione, cómo puedo solucionarlo?

De antemano les agradezco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema indicado :

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first.

Al principio se va a mostrar correctamente pero la segunda ocasión mostrará el error. En este caso debes crear una nueva instancia de la `List` para agregarla a tu AlerDialog y obviamente la carga de sus respectivos datos.

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Conductor.this);
            builder.setCancelable(true);

            //crear una nueva instancia.
            ListView lista_mensajes = new ListView(Conductor.this);

            builder.setView(lista_mensajes);
            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog = builder.show();
```

Comment: entonces debe estar esta instancia dos veces en mi codigo?

Comment: Las veces que sean necesarias si intentas agregar un ListView (u otra vista) en un AlertDialog. Trata agregando un ListView vacio y veras que funciona, pero sinceramente esto que estas realizando es poco ordinario, te recomiendo que al dar click para construir el AlertDialog obtenga en ese mismo método el ListView con sus respectivos datos.

Comment: He intentado hacer lo que me dices pero ahora el alertdialog me aparece vacio

Comment: Precisamente por lo que te comento, al dar click e instanciar el AlertDialog, debes crear la instancia del ListView a agregar! .=)

Comment: si tienes mucha razón y ya se solucionó mi error muchas gracias, aquí adjunte mi respuesta

Comment: Excelente Diego me da gusto solucionaras tu problema, Saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ

Answer (score 1):

ya lo pude solucionar,lo que hice fue remover la instancia de mi listview y por consiguiente su adaptador y tb el metodo onitemclicklistener y eso agregue en mi metodo de menu de la siguiente manera

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.sms_conductor:
                lista_mensajes = new ListView(Conductor.this);
                adaptador_mensajes = new Adaptador_mensajes(Conductor.this,arrayList);
                lista_mensajes.setAdapter(adaptador_mensajes);

                lista_mensajes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        TextView txt_id_mensaje_conductor = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_id_mensaje_conductor);
                        TextView txt_mensaje_conductor = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_mensaje_conductor);
                        String id_mensaje_conductor_txt = txt_id_mensaje_conductor.getText().toString();
                        String mensaje_conductor_txt = txt_mensaje_conductor.getText().toString();

                        Toast.makeText(Conductor.this, mensaje_conductor_txt+" "+id_mensaje_conductor_txt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Conductor.this);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setView(lista_mensajes);
                dialog = builder.create();
                dialog = builder.show();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```